# C# - Cannot deserialize JSON into List<T>

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

I'm fetching a list of entries in a BD with a GET request (I'm using RestSharp to make the request) and I want to deserialize the content of the response into a List.

The type of list elements is "Mileage":

```
public class Mileage
{
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    public int Travels { get; set; }
    public int Monday { get; set; }
    public int Tuesday { get; set; }
    public int Wednesday { get; set; }
    public int Thursday { get; set; }
    public int Friday { get; set; }
    public int Saturday { get; set; }
    public int Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

And the response.Content is like this:

```
{
"TheoreticalMileages": [
    {
      "BranchId": 36,
      "RouteId": 1860,
      "Travels": 10,
      "Monday": 132,
      "Tuesday": 89,
      "Wednesday": 92,
      "Thursday": 104,
      "Friday": 112,
      "Saturday": 0,
      "Sunday": 79
    },
    {
      "BranchId": 7,
      "RouteId": 2600,
      "Travels": 12,
      "Monday": 40,
      "Tuesday": 30,
      "Wednesday": 40,
      "Thursday": 100,
      "Friday": 121,
      "Saturday": 130,
      "Sunday": 0
    },
    {
      "BranchId": 23,
      "RouteId": 33,
      "Travels": 8,
      "Monday": 54,
      "Tuesday": 50,
      "Wednesday": 35,
      "Thursday": 50,
      "Friday": 67,
      "Saturday": 32,
      "Sunday": 30
    }
  ],
  "TotalRecords": 3
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON.NET to deserialize the object into a list of mileages. I've already tried to convert it to a List and an IEnumerable:

```
var mileages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Mileage>>(getAllResponse.Content);
```

But I get the same error with both types of collections: "Cannot deserialize the current json object because the type requires a json array[...]"

Is there a way to convert the object directly into a list? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your class is wrong let a robot create it for you: Visual Studio: Paste Special - Paste JSON as Classes or jsonutils.com

Comment: You need to wrap your list in a class with a `TheoreticalMileages` property taking the list. How should the deserializer know that it must skip the TheoreticalMileages key and only return it’s value as list?

Comment: NVM I didnt see the end of that JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON you're using isn't a list.  It's an object.  One of its *properties* happens to be a list.  Something like this:

```
public class MileageContainer
{
    public IEnumerable<Mileage> TheoreticalMileages { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to deserialize the JSON into that object:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MileageContainer>(getAllResponse.Content);
```

Comment: @AndreVillanueva Just a suggestion . i found following link to be use full. If u have the Json result use this link to generate class [Json to Class](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Thanks, that will help me a lot in the future :)